# Let multiple instances of same activity appear in task manager

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I read a lot about intents and flags but it is hard to learn because I am new to android development.

I created shortcuts on my home screen pointing to the WebActivity. Each shortcut includes an url as extra information. The user should be able to open one shortcut first and see the website using `WebView`, then go to the home screen and open shortcut 2 and after that return to shortcut1 instance via the task switcher. So I need: Multiple instances of one activity started from my shortcut and they have to be available in the task switcher.

**I am targeting API 21 but supporting Android 4.0 (19). I know that the task switching system was extended in Android 5.**